# .NET restore/build gets 401 when being invoke inside Github Action workflow with organization package

Tags: .net, github, nuget, github-actions, github-pages

I have a GitHub organization that has some packages pushed. They are accessible via [https://github.com/orgs/[REDACTED]/packages](https://github.com/orgs/%5BREDACTED%5D/packages), so they are not repository only. In one of my repos, I try to create package with contracts for other repos (microservices), but this repo uses one of the packages I mentioned before.

Here is my current YAML for building this contracts package:

```
name: Publish [REDACTED].Domain.Shared package
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - release/shared/*
    paths:
      - "src/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared/**"
jobs:
  Publish-Package:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
      contents: read
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: "8.x"
          source-url: https://nuget.pkg.github.com/[REDACTED]/index.json
        env:
          NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.ACTION_TOKEN}}
      - run: dotnet restore src/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared
      - run: dotnet build src/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared --no-restore
      - run: dotnet pack --configuration Release src/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared
      - run: dotnet nuget push src/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared/bin/Release/*.nupkg
```

and when it comes to `dotnet restore`, I'm getting:

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.100/NuGet.targets(156,5): warning : Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured. [/home/runner/work/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared.csproj]
> Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/[REDACTED]/download/[REDACTED]/index.json'.
> Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

My GitHub token has `repo:all`, `read:packages` and `write:packages` permissions set.

I don't know if it matters, but here is my NuGet.Config from the sln that contains this contracts library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="[REDACTED]" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/[REDACTED]/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceMapping>
        <packageSource key="nuget.org">
            <package pattern="*" />
        </packageSource>
        <packageSource key="[REDACTED]">
            <package pattern="[REDACTED].*" />
        </packageSource>
    </packageSourceMapping>
</configuration>
```

Token and NuGet.Config is the same for all repos, and they can all produce packages - until it comes to download a dependency of another package from my organization.

I tried to change permissions of token to all possible but it did not work. I also tried to remove dotnet auth from `actions/setup-dotnet@v3` in workflow, but it all returned same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the `secrets.ACTION_TOKEN` used in your workflow has the correct permissions and is valid. It should have [`read:packages` scope](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/about-permissions-for-github-packages#about-scopes-and-permissions-for-package-registries) at a minimum.

Modify your workflow to correctly authenticate with GitHub Packages. That involves setting up the NuGet CLI to use the GitHub token for authentication.

Remove the `source-url` parameter from the `actions/setup-dotnet@v3` step. That step was previously attempting to configure the NuGet source, but it may not have been correctly setting up authentication.

Instead of relying on the `actions/setup-dotnet` action to configure the NuGet source, try and add explicit steps to set up the NuGet credentials for accessing the GitHub Package Registry, with:

- a new step that initializes a new NuGet configuration ([`dotnet new nugetconfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new)). That makes sure any existing NuGet configuration that might conflict with your authentication settings is reset.
- another new step that adds the GitHub Package Registry as a NuGet source with the necessary authentication details. It uses the `dotnet nuget add source` command to add the GitHub Package Registry URL, along with the GitHub username and the personal access token (PAT) stored in `secrets.ACTION_TOKEN`. That command configures NuGet to use these credentials when accessing packages from the GitHub Package Registry.

```yaml
name: Publish [REDACTED].Domain.Shared package
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - release/shared/*
    paths:
      - "src/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared/**"
jobs:
  Publish-Package:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
      contents: read
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: "8.x"
      - name: Set up NuGet Credential Provider
        run: dotnet new nugetconfig
      - name: Add GitHub Package Registry to NuGet
        run: dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/[REDACTED]/index.json --name GPR --username [REDACTED] --password ${{secrets.ACTION_TOKEN}} --store-password-in-clear-text
      - run: dotnet restore src/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared
      - run: dotnet build src/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared --no-restore
      - run: dotnet pack --configuration Release src/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared
      - run: dotnet nuget push src/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared/bin/Release/*.nupkg
```

---

> I added your suggestions. Steps for Credential Provider and GPR are passing successfully, however I still get the same 401 error. My token has `repo, write:packages` permissions. I even generated another test token with the same parameters but it does not work either.

Just for testing, try a token with the `read:packages` permission in addition to `repo` and `write:packages`. The `read:packages` scope is essential for downloading packages. Make sure that the token is associated with a user who has access to the organization and the specific packages.

After setting up the credentials in the GitHub Actions workflow, add a step to print the final `NuGet.Config` file to ensure that it is correctly configured. Again, this is for testing (make sure to not expose your token in the workflow output).

```yaml
- name: Print NuGet Config for Debugging
    run: cat NuGet.Config
```

There could be an environment-specific issue. Try running the same commands locally on your machine with the same `NuGet.Config` and see if you can authenticate and restore packages successfully.

If there are multiple sources in your `NuGet.Config`, the order of sources can sometimes cause issues. Ensure that the GitHub Package Registry source is listed appropriately. The `dotnet restore` command should prioritize the GitHub source for your organization's packages.

Modify the `dotnet restore` command to explicitly specify the source. This would make sure the restore operation is attempting to use the GitHub Package Registry.

```yaml
- run: dotnet restore src/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared --source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/[REDACTED]/index.json"
```

---

> I can indeed see that `nuget.config` that is created on the GitHub server during workflow execution does not contain any credentials

The fact that the `NuGet.Config` file created during the GitHub Actions workflow does not contain credentials explains why you are still encountering a 401 Unauthorized error: the GitHub Actions runner is attempting to access the GitHub Package Registry without the necessary authentication, leading to this issue.

Double-check that the `dotnet nuget add source` command is executed correctly, with the correct syntax.
And check if the `secrets.ACTION_TOKEN` is correctly set in your repository's secrets, and that it is being passed correctly into the GitHub Actions environment. Sometimes, environment variables can be overlooked or misconfigured.

The GitHub Actions environment might have a restriction or a setting that prevents storing credentials in plain text in the `NuGet.Config` file. However, this is necessary for non-interactive authentication in CI/CD pipelines.

Re-verify that the GitHub token used has the correct permissions (`read:packages`, `write:packages`, and `repo`). And that the token is still valid and has not expired.

As a workaround, you can manually configure the `NuGet.Config` file in your repository with the required sources and then encrypt the credentials using a secure method. That file can then be decrypted and used during the GitHub Actions run.

Another approach is to use environment variables directly in the `dotnet restore` command for authentication. That way, you do not need to store the credentials in the `NuGet.Config` file. You can specify the credentials as part of the restore command.

```yaml
- run: dotnet restore src/[REDACTED]/[REDACTED].Domain.Shared --source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/[organization]/index.json" --configfile NuGet.Config --interactive false
   env:
      NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACTION_TOKEN }}
```

Consider adding debugging steps in your GitHub Actions workflow to print out (carefully, to avoid exposing the token) the results of each step. That can help identify where the process is failing.

---

Thre OP confirms in the comments:

> Got it. `--configfile` was the clue.
>
> I needed to add `--configfile nuget.config` parameter to *both* `dotnet nuget add source` and `dotnet restore`, and then, to push package, I had to add `--source [myPackageSource]`.
>
> However we still don't know why in this particular case those parameters are needed...

Comment: I added your suggestions. Steps for Credential Provider and GPR are passing successfully, however I still get the same 401 error. My token has `repo, write:packages` permissions. I even generated another test token with the same parameters but it does not work either.

Comment: I can indeed see that `nuget.config` that is created on GitHub server during workflow execution does not contain any credentials. It contains only `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!--To inherit the global NuGet package sources remove the <clear/> line below -->
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="GPR" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/[organization]/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>`. What can cause it?

Comment: @ervin I have edited the answer to, again, leave some suggestions.

Comment: I got it. `--configfile` was the clue. I needed to add `--configfile nuget.config` parameter to both `dotnet nuget add source` and `dotnet restore`, and then to push package, I had to add `--source [myPackageSource]`. Thank you very much for help. It is very good that it is working, however we still don't know why in this particular case those parameters are needed...

Comment: @ervin Great, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.